# What is wrong with the tone in this answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, be-nice-policy, writing

Recently I got accused by other user for using unacceptable "tone" for posting [the only helpful and reliable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20726310/285587) to their question.

I am apparently not the most courteous dude in the world, I have to admit. I am not a native speaker too. And I indeed have a very low opinion on a usual inhabitant of PHP tag, and most of time I am in a quite misanthropic mood in general. But I am trying hard to never let it out. And nobody can say I am dishonest. So, I can tell you that it wasn't my intention to insult or harass anyone. All I wanted is to emphasize and explain the problem.

So, the question is: Is the tone in this answer indeed too harsh to be acceptable? If so — what is certainly wrong with it? And what wording would you suggest? A neutral technical style preferably. I know that some would tell that the only acceptable tone is as though you are nursing a toddler. I am not *that* low opinion of the OP, and prefer just neutral style, to emphasize technical problems only.

Or is it just a case when someone just wished to feel insulted? At least such a case is quite possible. Some people indeed speculate too much on the words they hear, with totally unpredictable results. The technical issue in question indeed can be considered too silly and even ridiculed by someone. But it is apparently not my fault to point out to that problem and nowhere I ridiculed it, but just explained.

Comment: Not quite a matter of niceness, but wording in the referred answer doesn't look accurate. Post critisizes code / design and this makes references to the poster irrelevant: "I suspect that **you** indeed going a bit overboard... And to satisfy **your** wrong views, **you** over-engineered **your** query to the point of totally uncomprehensible mess." I think it would be more accurate to rephrase it like "I suspect that **this design** is indeed going a bit overboard... And to satisfy **these** wrong views, **the query** was over-engineered to the point of totally uncomprehensible mess."

Comment: ...have to admit, it took me a while to get used to writing code review comments in _impersonalized_ form. But after a bit of training, I managed to establish a fairly strong habit so that it doesn't take noticeable effort to spell things that way.

Comment: *Tone* is a useful consideration... certainly critical tone makes the "listener" less engaged, where friendly, kind, or humorous tone makes them *more* engaged.  But another powerful solution is simply to remove tone.  I say *powerful* because tone easily distracts, making delivery less powerful.  But you have to consider, for yourself, whether you are willing to *give up* getting that tone across.  (Also that external practice that may involve internal practices, like keeping "What happened?" distinct, from the "story" or "interpretation" our minds almost constantly add to what happened.)

Comment: Criticise the *code*, not the *author* of the code. Back up criticism with references or common terms for the bad pattern if possible, and/or describe effect of the poor choice. Avoid opinion-based language, or disclaim it with "in my opinion", so as not to state an opinion as an absolute fact. BTW I think the intent of the answer is good - just distance yourself and OP from the answer.

Comment: I think you can sometimes be somewhat acerbic, but I see nothing wrong with that specific answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a bit of a setup issue I'd say. The first two sentences are perhaps direct, but not problematic. Where one might argue it goes off-track (if you're that sensitive) is

> And to satisfy your wrong views, you over-engineered your query to the point of totally uncomprehensible mess.

That indeed sounds a bit harsh. Perhaps something along these lines would have worked better:

> Unfortunately, that might have lead to over-engineering your query. And that didn't make it really comprehensible.

It's only a slight difference, but it avoids the piling on of negatives I'd say, while still remaining clear.

Users might be sensitive to stuff like this. So if you can at all avoid it, try.

Comment: Well, "wrong views" was actually errr... a loan translation. And it bear no negative meaning in my native language. All I wanted to say that it's wrong intentions (or views) led to the problem.

Comment: Sure. The only "problem" is see with your particular structuring is that it might read as "this was bad, that was bad too, and to make things even worse you also....". A bit of a stylistic change to "this wasn't great, that neither, which unfortunately lead you to..." could help with the tone.

Answer (score 8):

**You are so blind by your own mess of an answer that you brainwashed yourself into thinking your answer is even remotely valid**

Jokes apart:

It's all a question of approach.

> And to satisfy your wrong views, you over-engineered your query to the point of totally uncomprehensible mess.

This part might be a little off-topic or unnecessary. Other than that the answer looks perfect to me.

Maybe the users thinks you are screaming when writing in bold. You never know. But also:

> That's exactly the problem. I have seen your interventions. You do it so often without been rebuffed that you think it is OK. Well, it isn't.

The approach was a bit rough. But the user clearly have a personal grudge against you so I wouldn't be bothered with that.

Answer (score 7):

Two phrases stand out to me as being worth changing.  First "your wrong views".  You could probably soften this a bit.  It seems overly harsh.  You then follow it up with the second issue "your query [is a] totally uncomprehensible mess".  Even if I agree with the sentiment, the tone here does come off as a bit..undesirable.  Honestly, the opening sentence, "I suspect that you indeed going a bit overboard with the whitelisting." both has a softer tone, and also conveys all of the information of the last sentence in that paragraph.  Given that, you can probably just remove that last line of the paragraph entirely without really detracting from the answer's content.

Having said that, the answer isn't particularly bad.  One can always do better, but I would say that the user did overreact.  Such is the nature of the interwebs.

Comment: You may notice that first sentence is but a quote from the OP. May be I had to explain that in the question too

Comment: @YourCommonSense I see that now, yes.  It makes it all the more appropriate.  I highly doubt that line is what the OP had a problem with.

Answer (score 2):

The first time you start off with a slightly bad tone is when you use the unnecessary filler word "even" in your second sentence. But the only part of your answer that has a serious tone problem is the next (third) sentence:

> And to satisfy your wrong views, you over-engineered your query to the
> point of totally uncomprehensible mess.

The "And" is inappropriate because sentence 3 is an explanation of sentences 1 & 2, not an additional mistake. The sentence packs in three negatives ("wrong", "over-engineered", "totally uncomprehensible mess") with the last one unnecessarily amplified. As @gnat points out, that sentence also contains a lot of "you"s. Hence, it's easy to take that as an attack, especially so early into your answer.

I'll address the three trigger words one by one:

- You mentioned that "wrong views" was a loan translation. You were looking for the word "misconceptions". The main issue with this one is that it's unclear what views you're referring to. You have to make clear that this misconception hasn't been mentioned yet and will be explained later in your post. Also, it's a single misconception, but by using the plural you're making the OP look more incompetent than they are.
- "over-engineered" is the correct term there. I wouldn't tip-toe around it because doing so would sacrifice too much clarity. But together with the rest of the sentence it contributes to the bad tone.
- Extending the simple concept of "incomprehensible" to the long phrase "to the point of totally uncomprehensible mess" makes it sound worse than it is. I recommend being a lot more careful with superlatives like "totally". The word "mess" also has a negative connotation. "to the point of" is not completely inocuous either because it suggests that the mess is extreme.

I took the liberty to replace that sentence by:

> By protecting constant values, you over-engineered your query, making it difficult to read.

Turns out that you only need three words to replace the vague "wrong views"/ "misconception" with the specific issue. And "difficult to read" sounds slightly less harsh than "incomprehensible".

Feel free to edit your SO post and improve.